# Expectation of random matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, expected-value, random-matrices, convexity-inequality

Assume $Q$ is a positive definite random matrix such that $0 < \lambda_{\min}(Q)....\leq \lambda_{\max}(Q) \leq 1$ holds. I want to show that
\begin{align}
E\left[\frac{\lambda_{\min}(Q)}{\lambda_{\min}(Q)+\lambda_{\max}(Q)}\right] \geq \frac{\lambda_{\min}(E[Q])}{\lambda_{\min}(E[Q])+\lambda_{\max}(E[Q])}
\end{align}

Or I want to show the following Kantorovich type inequality for expected values:
\begin{align}
E\left[\frac{(y^Ty)^2}{(y^TQy)(y^TQ^{-1}y)}\right] \geq \frac{4\lambda_{\min}(E[Q])\lambda_{\max}(E[Q])}{\left[\lambda_{\min}(E[Q])+\lambda_{\max}(E[Q])\right]^2}
\end{align}

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to use the convexity of the function $\lambda_{\min}/(\lambda_{\min}+\lambda_{\max})$. then, I need to prove the concavity of the function $f=\lambda_{\max}/\lambda_{\min}$. not sure about the convexity though.